Using multiple encryption keys in Couchbase
I'm using Couchbase with field level encryption and it works fine when using a default encryption key, but now I need to support different encryption keys for different fields.
I use to have my cluster configured with a default encrypter and that is why it was working fine:
var cryptoManager = DefaultCryptoManager.Builder()
    .Decryptor(provider.Decryptor())
    .DefaultEncryptor(provider.Encryptor("my-key")) // Default encryptor was being defined
    .Build();

But now I'm adding many keys to the provider and then adding them to the cryptoManager:
var keys = GetEncryptionKeys();
var provider = new AeadAes256CbcHmacSha512Provider(new AeadAes256CbcHmacSha512Cipher(), new Keyring(keys));

var cryptoManagerBuilder = DefaultCryptoManager.Builder();
cryptoManagerBuilder.Decryptor(provider.Decryptor());
foreach (var k in keys)
{
    // Adds the encryption keys one by one
    // So I end up with a list of keys: "my-key1", "my-key2", "my-key3"
    cryptoManagerBuilder.Encryptor(k.Id, provider.Encryptor(k.Id)); 
}
var cryptoManager = cryptoManagerBuilder.Build();

That code works fine, but when I try to write or read files, I get this error:
Missing encryptor for alias ''
I am correctly defining my encryption key on the model field

I would expect Couchbase to identify that I want to use "my-key" from the list of encryption keys that I provided, but I get that error instead.
Question
Is there a way for not having to specify a default encryptor and just use what is defined on each model property?

I downloaded the Couchbase library code for .NET and if I'm not mistaken, looks like the "KeyName" from the EncryptedField attribute is never used, causing the encryption key alias to be always null and ending up falling to the default encrypted...
https://github.com/couchbase/dotnet-couchbase-encryption
